# Predict Collision Between 2 Uniform Circular Motion Objects

Tags: plane-geometry

this is my first question on the forum and my algebra is rusty so please be indulgent ^^'

I want to predict collision between two uniform circular motion objects for which i know velocity (angular speed in radian), distance from the origin (radius), cartesian coordinate of the center of the circle.

I can get Cartesian position for each object given for t time (timestamp) using :

`Oa.x = ra X cos(wa X t)`

`Oa.y = ra X sin(wa X t)`

`Oa.x`: Object A x coordinates
`ra`: radius of a Circle A
`wa`: velocity of object A (angular speed in radian)
`t`: time (timestamp)

Same goes for object b (Ob)

I want to find t such that `||Ca - Cb|| = (rOa + rOb)`

`rOa`: radius of object a

Squaring both side and expanding give me this :
`||Ca-Cb||^2 = (rOa+rOb)^2`

`(ra * cos (wa * t) - rb / cos (wb * t))^2 + (ra * sin (wa * t) - rb / sin (wb * t))^2 = (ra+rb)^2`

From that i should get a quadratic polynomial that i can solve for t, but how can i find a condition that tell me if such a t exist ? And possibly, how to solve it for t ?

Comment: DO you have two object circling the origion?

Comment: @Moti I have different 2 object circling 2 different origin

Comment: Your equations, that are not written in standard way for some reason, are not reflecting on this.